# UIView pan gesture along Y axis

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have a UIView that I can drag and drop along the Y axis that snaps into 1 of 2 positions. The issue is that I have to drag it over a certain point in the Y axis in order for it to snap into place. This feels clunky when you try to quickly swipe but don't make it past that specific Y axis and it snaps back to the start position.

My desired goal is to have it snap into 1 of 2 positions depending on the direction the user was swiping when he released the UIView.

```
@objc func panGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
    let currentY = self.frame.minY
    let partialY = (window?.frame.height)!-194
    let halfWayPoint = ((window?.frame.height)!/2)-40

    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: currentY + translation.y, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

    switch recognizer.state {

    case .changed:

        // Prevent scrolling up past y:0
        if currentY <= 0
        {
            self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        }

    case .ended:

        // Snap to 80 (y) (expanded)
        if currentY < 80 || currentY > 80 && currentY < halfWayPoint
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.62, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (true) in
                self.isExpanded = true
            })
        }

        // Snap back to partial (y) (original position)
        if currentY > partialY || currentY < partialY && currentY > halfWayPoint
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.62, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.62, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:
                {
                    recognizer.view!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: partialY, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
            }, completion: {(true) in
                self.isExpanded = false
            })
        }

    default:
        print("Default")
    }
```

As you can see halfWayPoint is the point in which the view must be over or under in order to determine the position it snaps into. This is ineffective and I would like to do it depending on the direction (up or down) the user is dragging the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use UIPanGestureRecognizers [velicoty(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity) method.
It gives you the speed of the swipe (in points per second).

If you just add it to the `currentY` (preferably scaled with some constant), you will get that flicky feeling, and gesture will feel more natural.

Just replace
`let currentY = self.frame.minY` with `let currentY = self.frame.minY + recognizer.velocity(in: nil).y * someConstant` and play with `someConstant` until you get the feeling you want.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it close enough with 0.01 as the constant. Need to play around with it a bit more but that works well